# Failed Create Launch Config with Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I've try to create new Launch Config at AWS with ansible after new AMI create, here's my script playbook :

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: create AMI
    ec2_ami:
      region: "ap-southeast-x"
      instance_id: "i-xxxxxx"
      name: "My AMI {{ ansible_date_time.date }} {{ ansible_date_time.hour }}-{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}"
      wait: yes
      state: present
    register: ami

  - name: create LC
    ec2_lc:
      name: "My LC {{ ansible_date_time.date }} {{ ansible_date_time.hour }}-{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}"
      image_id: "{{ ami.image_id }}"
      key_name: "my_key"
      security_groups: "sg-xxxx"
      instance_type: t2.medium
    register: lcnew
```

but when i try to run, i've got this message :

```
ERROR: ec2_lc is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
```

Comment: What is your Ansible version?

Comment: my ansible version 2.0.0, i've found the root cause :D
there's no module ec2_lc at my ansible module path, I've already updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Ansible *2.0.0*, you must have installed from git I guess. Did you clone the repository recursive? Modules are implemented through a git submodule. `git clone git://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive`

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source

Comment: i install ansible from apt ... i'm planning to remove ansible from apt and get new one from git